# The 'Pods-Runner' target has libraries with conflicting names: libgsdk.a

Tags: swift, flutter

i am trying to run flutter project on ios simulator

```
[!] The 'Pods-Runner' target has libraries with conflicting names: libgsdk.a.

    /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.14.3/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.14.3/lib/cocoapods/installer/xcode/target_validator.rb:67:in `verify_no_duplicate_names'
    /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.14.3/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.14.3/lib/cocoapods/installer/xcode/target_validator.rb:58:in `block (2 levels) in
    verify_no_duplicate_framework_and_library_names'
    /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.14.3/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.14.3/lib/cocoapods/installer/xcode/target_validator.rb:48:in `each_key'
    /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.14.3/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.14.3/lib/cocoapods/installer/xcode/target_validator.rb:48:in `block in
    verify_no_duplicate_framework_and_library_names'
    /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.14.3/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.14.3/lib/cocoapods/installer/xcode/target_validator.rb:47:in `each'
    /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.14.3/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.14.3/lib/cocoapods/installer/xcode/target_validator.rb:47:in
    `verify_no_duplicate_framework_and_library_names'
    /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.14.3/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.14.3/lib/cocoapods/installer/xcode/target_validator.rb:37:in `validate!'
    /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.14.3/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.14.3/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:666:in `validate_targets'
    /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.14.3/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.14.3/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:164:in `install!'
    /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.14.3/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.14.3/lib/cocoapods/command/install.rb:52:in `run'
    /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.14.3/libexec/gems/claide-1.1.0/lib/claide/command.rb:334:in `run'
    /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.14.3/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.14.3/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:52:in `run'
    /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.14.3/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.14.3/bin/pod:55:in `<top (required)>'
    /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.14.3/libexec/bin/pod:25:in `load'
    /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.14.3/libexec/bin/pod:25:in `<main>'
```

Flutter project should run well on ios

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After spending almost a day finding a way to get rid of duplicates when building Flutter project on ios, I found an answer,

- I have commented on a line of code that was checking duplicates in cocoaPods file (***/opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.14.3/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.14.3/lib/cocoapods/installer/xcode/target_validator.rb:67:in `verify_no_duplicate_names***')
- After making those changes, I ran the project and I found the packages that were causing the duplicates.
- After removing those packages and commenting wherever I have used them, I have uncommented the line of code from the cocoa pods file
- The app runs successfully by removing those packages and fixing a few errors in `info.plist`.
- Afterward, I continued to find a way to replace the packages that caused the issue.

DO NOT FAIL TO TRY